# При создании нового проекта react создает файлы npm при использовании yarn

Tags: npm, create-react-app, yarn

Такая проблема. При создании нового проекта react использую yarn . Но он создаёт файлы и npm . Как это исправить ?

Comment: а что вы имеете ввиду под npm файлами?

Comment: Создаёт папку node_modules ( при создании через yarn, вроде не должен ее создавать )

Comment: не, это не относится к npm, npm и yarn это пакетные менеджеры, они формируют node-modules скачивая и устанавливая их для дальнейшего использования, node.js - отдельная программа, она использует node-modules

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Думал что не должно быть этих файлов